# Formatting a date in java

Tags: java

I have the two Date objects which I am trying to format from being in `MM/DD/YYYY` format to `"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"` format.

The current approach I am using is to first format those dates using `SimpleDateFormat` which will return two `Strings`, then I have to convert this string back to Date to get the formatted final `Date` objects.

So I was wondering if there was a simpler way to change the Date object format without going in many steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The format is irrelevant.  `Date` simply represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

Remember, `Date` has no concept of format, it doesn't care.

You should simply format the `Date` object with whatever formatters you need...

For example...

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMMM EE").format(date));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM yyyy").format(date));
System.out.println(date);
```

Outputs...

```
Wed Jan 22 11:55:18 EST 2014
22/01/2014 11:55:18 AM
22/01/2014
2014 January Wed
Wednesday January 2014
Wed Jan 22 11:55:18 EST 2014
```

Note how the first and last values don't change.  `Date` has no internal concept of format, that's the responsibility of the formatter.

For example, if I took the `String` value `22/01/2014` and parsed it back to a `Date` using `SimpleDateFormat`

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("22/01/2014");
```

And then outputted the `date` value...

```
System.out.println(date);
```

It would output something like...

```
Wed Jan 22 00:00:00 EST 2014
```

The format has being lost.  It would need to use an appropriate formatter to change what is displayed

Comment: If I understood you correctly here, what you mean is that if I have for example Date1 object, no matter how I format its date it will remain with the same original format it had before. So to use a formatted date, I must take the String output from the SimpleDateFormat or DateFormatter...correct?

Comment: Take a `String`, parse it to `Date` (using an appropriate formatter for the input `String`).  Once you have a `Date`, you can pass it to whatever formatter you want and it won't change the `Date` object in any way.  Take a look at the examples I linked at the end of the question

Comment: The example you provided assumes that I am initially having a String with a date, which is not the case. I initially have a Date object with the date I need to format...makes sense?

Comment: Okay, so simply pass the `Date` object to whatever formatters you want to use. It makes no difference.  A `Date` has not format of it's own, it's just a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch...